# How to use Middle Ware in Azure Function in start up class

Tags: azure-functions

I am looking to use middle ware to decrypt the http request coming to azure function in start up.cs class.
below is my start up class

public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
{
public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
{
if (builder == null)
throw new ArgumentNullException(null, new Exception());
ConfigureServices(builder.Services).BuildServiceProvider(true);
}

IFunctionsHostBuilder does not contain any method like builder.UseMiddleware? So not getting idea how to do that.
can somebody help

Answer (score 0):

How to use Middle Ware in Azure Function in start up class

Firstly Azure Functions won't have `startup` class by default, But Services can be added using `IWebJobStartup` and secondly you cannot add custom middleware in startup class.
Rather you can create your own middleware function by implementing `IHttpMiddleware` or sub-class `HttpMiddleware`

```
public class UtcRequestDateMiddleWare : HttpMiddleware
{
    public override Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
       context.Response.Headers["x-request-date-utc"] = System.DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("o");
    }
}
```

check the [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58796923/how-to-add-custom-startup-class-in-http-trigger-azure-function-app) for further reference

Find how to create [Middleware Functions](https://github.com/umamimolecule/azure-functions-http-middleware#creating-your-own-middleware)